# Set Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData using C#

Tags: c#, windows, registry

How to set a new path to Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData using C#

Answer (score 5):

Please don't do this.

These folder paths don't belong to your application, and changing them in this manner will not work for a domain user who has a folder redirection policy.